# How to have kind of a technical writer role in wp website

Tags: user-roles

A reader from my website said she was a technical writer and would like to contribute by helping polishing the posts. But she is still a new learner in the technical field.

So what I probably need is a role which she can edit all posts but can't directly publish them without moderation. I have viewed the existing roles in WP but it doesn't seem to me that they will suit my situation. Which approach should I follow in this case?